# How to send 206 status code when using active_model_serializer gem and Rails API and will_paginate/kaminari

Tags: active-model-serializers, rails-api

I'm using AMS, Rails 5.2.2 API with `will_paginate` gem. It works as needed but the response code is `200` instead of `206`

```
#adsresses_controller

def index
  @addresses = Address.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
  json_response(@addresses, :ok, include: ['shop', 'shop.country'])
end
```

where `json_response` is just a method defined in `controllers/concerns/response.rb`:

```
module Response
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def json_response(object, status = :ok, opts = {})
    response = {json: object, status: status}.merge(opts)
    render response
  end
...
end
```

The question is what is the best rule to send the correct response, - 200 or 206 in case of the paginated response ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

> 2.2.12.4 The :status Option Rails will automatically generate a response with the correct HTTP status code (in most cases, this is 200
>   OK).  You can use the :status option to change this:

```
render status: 500
render status: :forbidden
```

Your response code is

> 200

because you ask for it with `:ok`.

You should work around that with something like :

```
json_response(@addresses, 206, include: ['shop', 'shop.country'])
```

or

```
json_response(@addresses, :partial_content, include: ['shop', 'shop.country'])
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206

> The HTTP 206 Partial Content success status response code indicates
>   that the request has succeeded and has the body contains the requested
>   ranges of data, as described in the Range header of the request.

So mostly depend on your application I think.

Comment: Yeah, I knew all that. The trick is that you will have to manage the status code manually in case if the response is paginated or not, i.e. if `@addresses.size` is more than 25 for example - you respond with `206` status (`:partial_content`), if not, you send `200`(`:ok`).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to was to add a helper method to `controllers/concerns/response.rb` to be able to return the right status for paginated response:

```
def paginated_response_status(collection)
  collection.size > WillPaginate.per_page ? :partial_content : :ok
end
```

and use it in `AdressesController` actions when needed:

```
#controllers/api/addresses_controller.rb

def index
  @addresses = Address.all
  paginate(
    json: @addresses, 
      include: ['shop', 'shop.country'],
      status: paginated_response_status(@addresses) 
  )
end
```

The above example was for `will_paginate` gem and `api-pagination` gem.

Hope this helps.